# PDO General error: 2014 Cannot execute queries while other unbuffered queries are active when trying to LOCK TABLES

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, table-locking, unbuffered-queries

I am updating someone's old old code from using `mysql()` to using `PDO`. In one place they have some `LOCK TABLES` commands to prevent two users from accessing the same data at the same time. When running `LOCK TABLES`, `PDO` throws "General Error: 2014 Cannot execute queries while other unbuffered queries are active".

I made some test code to eliminate other variables. The system runs on Ubuntu 18 / PHP 7.2 / MySQL 5.7.27:

```
try {
    $_DB=new PDO("mysql:host=".DBHOST.";dbname=".DBNAME.";charset=utf8", DBUSER, DBPASS,array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8", PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT => "5",  PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false, PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_DIRECT_QUERY=>false,PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY=>true ));      

    // This gives the 2014 error. Any queries following this get the 2014 error.
    // Any queries before this work fine.
    $_DB->query("LOCK TABLES Inspections WRITE");

    $_DB->query("UNLOCK TABLES");
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    logError("Error : ".$e->getMessage());           
    // per @dharman's comment 
    //exit();
    throw($e);
}
```

I also tried adding a `$_DB->beginTransaction` before the `LOCK TABLES` and `$_DB->commit` after the `UNLOCK TABLES`, but still I get the same error.

I have tried various combination of `ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES` and `MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY`, but nothing seems to make any difference.

Comment: Please do not catch the exception just to print the error message. Either leave the exceptions alone or rethrow it if you need.

Comment: Thanks @Dharman - good to know.

Comment: It would be good to know why does your code require the lock? There is probably a way to do the same without the lock.

Comment: I think it is used to ensure that if two people try to edit an Inspection at the same time, there won't be a race condition between the checking to see if someone is editing it and updating to say that I am editing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`exec()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.exec.php) instead `query()`. `exec()` does not expect any return values, which is exactly what `LOCK TABLES` needs.

```
$pdo->exec("LOCK TABLES Inspections WRITE");
```